# Имя файла с переводом каретки

Tags: python, файлы, python-3.x

Не как не могу понять, как убрать перевод каретки (\n) из имени файла.
Файл создаю следующим образом:

```
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-

input_file = open("test", 'r')

for line in input_file:
    NAMEFILE = line+".txt"
    print (NAMEFILE)
    output_file = open("./testfolder/"+NAMEFILE, 'w')
    output_file.write("String:"+line)
    output_file.close()

input_file.close()
```

Содержание исходного файла простое:

```
123234
123456
....
```

Создаются файлы с именами строк, то есть 123234.txt 123456.txt и т.д. но между именем и расширением присутствует символ перевода строки, как его убрать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`line.strip()` - убирает пробелы и переводы строк в начале и конце строки

можно и только переводы строк убрать:  `line.strip("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с vinger4:

```
NAMEFILE = line.strip("\n")+".txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

я думаю правильней было бы задаться тем почему он возникает.